# difference in returned FetchInfo object from gitPython when there is something to fetch/pull vs when there isn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitpython

I'm trying to assess whether there have been changes in a remote repository that I may need to pull before a certain piece of code.

I do that by fetching a `FetchInfo` object via `fetch()` to a remote origin:

```
>>> import git
>>> my_repo = git.Repo.init(my_dir)
>>> repo_fetch = my_repo.remotes.origin.fetch()[0]
>>> repo_fetch
<git.remote.FetchInfo object at 0x10192c650>
```

However, I haven't been able to clearly see in [the documentation](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=Fetch#git.remote.FetchInfo) what the difference is between when there are things to fetch/pull and when there aren't.

I know `pull()` outputs a `str` variable containing `Already up to date.` when the local repo is up to date but I don't want to pull, I just want to fetch.

I see some differences in its attributes when I know no changes are present in the remote repo:

```
>>> repo_fetch.ref 
<git.RemoteReference "refs/remotes/origin/master">
>>> repo_fetch.flags
4
>>> repo_fetch.note
''
>>> repo_fetch.old_commit
>>> repo_fetch.remote_ref_path
'master    '
```

and when there *are* changes:

```
>>> repo_fetch.ref 
<git.RemoteReference "refs/remotes/origin/master">
>>> repo_fetch.flags
64
>>> repo_fetch.note
''
>>> repo_fetch.old_commit
<git.Commit "[some_string]">
>>> repo_fetch.remote_ref_path
' '
```

Answer (score 3):

The key is the `flags` attribute, not very intuitively or clearly presented in [the documentation](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=Fetch#git.remote.FetchInfo):

```
ERROR = 128
FAST_FORWARD = 64
FORCED_UPDATE = 32
HEAD_UPTODATE = 4
NEW_HEAD = 2
NEW_TAG = 1
REJECTED = 16
TAG_UPDATE = 8
```

For the purposes of the question, as long as the flags are not equal to `4` (`HEAD_UPTODATE`), I need to take action differently than if both local and remote repositories are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to check if your local repo is up to date in GitPython using fetch() should be specifying the argument `verbose`.

The default value of `verbose` is `True`, which behaves similar to `git fetch -v`. It tells Git to print you some information even when there's nothing important for you to know. So in cases where you just want to know if pulling is necessary, do `fetch(verbose=False)`, it will give you an empty list if there is nothing to do. However, keep in mind that there will only be `FetchInfo` objects in the list if you haven't fetched it yet.